# TableView didselect performSegue on double tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using performSegue in UItableView didselect method with switch case, Sometimes it performs segue on single tap and sometimes double tap.
I'm using 2 sections in UITableView if someone can help me with this issue?
Here is didselect code

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationVC") as? NotificationVC {
                vc.link = "NOTIFICATION"
                vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        } else {
            let identifier = banners[indexPath.row].link
            switch identifier{
            case "GOLD":
                print("Move to \(identifier!)")
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "vouchGold", sender: self)
            case "RETAIL":
                print("Move to \(identifier!)")
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "vouchRetail", sender: self)
            case "FUSION":
                print("Move to \(identifier!)")
//                performSegue(withIdentifier: "vouchRetail", sender: selfr)
                if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fusions") as? HomeVC {
                    vc.linkType = "FUSION"
                    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            case "SOCIAL":
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "vouchSocial", sender: self)
            case "TRAVEL":
                print("Move to \(identifier!)")
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "vouchTravel", sender: self)
            case "EVENTS":
                print("Move to \(identifier!)")
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "vouchEvents", sender: self)
            case "WHATSAPP":
                print("Move to \(identifier!)")
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "vouchWhatsapp", sender: self)
            default :
                link = banners[indexPath.row].link
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "vouchURL", sender: self)
                print("No Identifier \(String(describing: self.banners[indexPath.row].link))")
            }

        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the focus with this line end of `didSelectRowAt`

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
```

Comment: on every case? or at last in method?

Comment: Thank you so much it's working fine now...
I got it that it needs to be deselect when move to new VC but can u explain me little bit more about it?